# Automatically updating table column with name of table using MapBasic

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, table

Does anyone know a straightforward way in MapBasic to automatically update a table column with the name of the table the column exists in?

Going from the MapBasic reference guide it seems the TableInfo function should serve this purpose but I can't seem to get it to work. In the MapBasic window whenever you use that function it says not unrecognised command.

Comment: Next time it might be a good idea to provide the statement that you try to run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
update table_id set some_field = TableInfo(table_id,1)
```